# Java - Reverse String null error

Tags: java, string, null

The input is meant to appear like this, example.
\n
Kazan R
\n
6789
\n
Nzk462
\n

However the output I receive looks like this
kzn462nullnzk
Why is this? and How can i solve it?

```
private void btnGenerateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    secondname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your surname:");
    firstname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your firstname:");
    idno = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your idno:");
    nametag = firstname.substring(0, 1);
    initials = secondname + " " + nametag;

    int randnum;
    do {
        randnum = (int) (Math.random() * 900) + 100;
    } while (randnum % 2 != 0);

    code = secondname.replaceAll("[aeiou || AEIOU](?!\\b)", "")+randnum ;
    txaDisplay.append(initials + '\n' + idno.substring(6,10) + '\n' + code);

    int length = secondname.length();
    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reverse = reverse + secondname.charAt(i);
    }
    String end = reverse + code;

   txaDisplay.append( reverse);
```

Comment: What is the input, what is the output and what gets transformed or randomly added how?

Comment: Where's your `reverse` string definition ? I don't see it inside your method, must be outside, can you add that as well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use

```
new StringBuilder(secondname).reverse().toString()
```

to reverse your `String`? It's better, simple and more maintanable.

Comment: @ricardo.cardin our teacher does not want us to use StringBuilder

Comment: @rubin.kazan if this question is an homework, I think that the best way to solve it should be to debug your code step by step :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Get the character array from your source string
2. Create a new char array of same length
3. Start iterating from 0 to (sourceStringLength-1)
4. In each iteration, get the last character
       from the end in your source array and populate in your new array
5. Create a new string from this new array

   ```
       String source = "abcdefg";
       char[] chars = source.toCharArray();
       char[] reverseChars = new char[source.length()];
       int len = source.length();
       for(int i= 0; i < len; i++){
           reverseChars[i] = chars[len-1-i];
       }
       String reverse = new String(reverseChars);
       System.out.println(reverse);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Since You don't want to use StringBuilder/StringBuffer.

Try this

```
String reversedString="";
for(int i=inputString.length-1;i>=0;){
   reversedString+=inputString.charAt(i--);  
}
```

Comment: This one is simple to write but creates lots of temporary strings behind the scenes but this is ok as it's just for educational purpose. In real scenarios, we are most likely to use StringBuilder :)

Comment: Yeah true but unfortunately , As it is a homework that is why Restriction given to him

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your definition of reverse, maybe you have something like:

```
String reverse;
```

Then you don't initialize your "reverse" so when your program makes the first concatenation in your loop, it looks like this:

```
reverse = null + secondname.charAt(i);
```

The null value is converted to a string so it can be visible in the output.

I hope this information helps you.

Good Luck.